# Navigator issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am a beginner in React Native and I want to create the following project:

I have a component called MainContainer, which is a NavigationContainer (Tab.Navigator) with several Tab.Screen components: Home, MenuForTeacher, ScanCode, and Settings.

Within MenuForTeacher, there is another Tab.Navigator, this time using material-top-tabs, with two Tab.Screen components: homeStack and AddForAllClasses.

Inside homeStack, there is a react-navigation-stack with two screens: AddForTeacher (the default screen) and ClassName. I want to add a button in AddForTeacher, so that when it is tapped, ClassName will appear.

I implemented this design because ClassName shouldn't be part of the MainContainer. Therefore, it doesn't have the bottom navigation bar but instead, in the header, only a 'button' allowing users to navigate back to the AddForTeacher screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJAVs.png)

The issue is :

```
ERROR  Error: This navigator has both navigation and container props, so it is unclear if it should own its own state. Remove props: "route" if the navigator should get its state from the navigation prop. If the navigator should maintain its own state, do not pass a navigation prop.
```

*** This project is for learning in React Native, so feel free to provide any critiques. I'm open to feedback as it helps me learn more about this framework.

## MainContainer

```
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import React,{useContext} from 'react';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import Settings from './screens/Settings';

import ScanCode from './screens/ScanCode';

import {AuthContext} from '../App';
import MenuForTeacher from './screens/screensForTeacher/MenuForTeacher';

const homeName = 'Home';
const settingsName = 'Settings';
const scanCodeName = 'ScanCode';
const menuForTeacher = 'Menu';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


function MainContainer() {
  const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);
  //const [email, setEmail] = React.useState(Email);
  //console.log("email in MainContainer"+email)
  return (
    <>
    {console.log("maincontainer user"+user)}
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={homeName}
        screenOptions={({route}) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === homeName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline';
            } else if (route.name === settingsName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'settings-sharp' : 'settings-outline';
            } else if (route.name === scanCodeName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'scan' : 'scan';
            }
            else if (route.name === menuForTeacher && user==="teacher") {
              iconName = focused ? 'school' : 'school';
            }

             
            return <Icon name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: '#1A3C40',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
           
          headerShown: route.name !== homeName ? true : false,
          headerTintColor: '#EDE6DB',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#1D5C63',
          },  
        })}>         
        <Tab.Screen name={homeName} component={Home} />
        {(user==="teacher")?
          (<Tab.Screen name={menuForTeacher} component={MenuForTeacher} />)
        :null}
        <Tab.Screen name={scanCodeName} component={ScanCode} />
        <Tab.Screen name={settingsName} component={Settings} />        
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
}
export default MainContainer
```

## MenuForTeacher

```
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import React,{useContext} from 'react';


import {AuthContext} from '../../../App';

import NavigatorAddForTeacher from "./homeStack";
import AddForAllClasses from "./AddForAllClasses";


const addForTeacher = 'My classes';
const addForAllClasses = 'All classes';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();




function MenuForTeacher() {
  const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={addForTeacher}
         screenOptions={() => ({
          tabBarActiveTintColor: '#1A3C40',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        })}>
        <Tab.Screen name={addForTeacher} component={NavigatorAddForTeacher} />
        <Tab.Screen name={addForAllClasses} component={AddForAllClasses} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </>
  );
}
export default MenuForTeacher;
```

## homeStack

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import AddForTeacher from './AddForTeacher';
import ClassName from './ClassName';

const screens ={
    AddForTeacher:{
        screen: AddForTeacher
    },
    ClassName:{
        screen: ClassName
    }
};

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

## AddForTeacher

```
import {
    Text, View,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity,ScrollView
  } from 'react-native';

import API_BASE_URL from '../../../../config';
import {AuthContext} from '../../../App';
import React,{useContext, useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';







const AddForTeacher = ({navigation}) =>{
    const {setClassSelectByTeahcer} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const {classSelectByTeahcer} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const {email} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [classes,setClasses] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    
    const getJwtTokenFromAsyncStorage = async () => {
        ...
      };

    const fetchClass = async () =>{
        ...
    }

    const handleClassNamePress = (item) => {
      navigation.navigate('ClassName');
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (isLoading) {
        fetchClass();
      }
    }, [isLoading]);

    return (
      <>
        <ScrollView style={styles.contanerClasses}>
          {classes.map((item, index) => (
            <View key={item.NomeClasse} style={styles.contanerClass}>
              <View style={styles.eatchClass}>
                <Text>{item.NomeClasse}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.horizontalLine} />
              <View style={styles.content}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => handleClassNamePress(item.NomeClasse)}
                // style={}
                >
                  <View style={styles.buttonAdd}>
                    <Icon name={'add-outline'} size={24} />
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </>
    );

}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    content:{
        
    },
    horizontalLine: {
        height: 2,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        marginVertical: 10,
        marginLeft:5,
        marginRight:5,
    },
    contanerClass:{
        padding:10,
        margin:10,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderRadius: 20,
        borderWidth: 1, 
    },
    contanerClasses:{
        margin:10,
    },
    eatchClass:{
       // borderColor: 'black',
        //borderRadius: 20,
        //borderWidth: 1, 
        
        //borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        //width:"80%",
    }
})
export default AddForTeacher;
```

## ClassName

```
import { de } from "date-fns/locale"
import { Text } from "react-native"

const ClassName = () =>{
    //const { name } = navigation.params;

  return (
    <View >
      <Text>{"hello"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default ClassName;
```